# Check if IP is banned

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this code, and it works on my localhost using MAMP perfectly. But as soon as I transfer it to a live website with an online database, it just tells me i'm banned no matter what.

```
    <?php

include "db/connect.php";

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $userIp = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $userIp = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $userIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

$ipQuery = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM banned_ip WHERE ip='".$userIp."'");
$ipCheck = mysqli_num_rows($ipQuery);

if($userIp == $ipCheck) {
  }
else{
    die ('You are banned from this site!');
}

?>
```

Comment: `if($userIp == $ipCheck) {` — This is pointless. You're comparing the user's IP address with the return value from `mysqli_num_rows()`. That is NEVER going to be equal.

Comment: Well is your IP in the database?

Comment: Nope, the database is cleared.

Comment: @AmalMurali But it works when I use it offline. If i use my ban page to insert my IP into the database, and then refresh the page it tells me i'm banned. If I remove it from the database I can browse freely.

Comment: limit also should be set as LIMIT 1

Comment: this is amazing question, in a way

Comment: Gee, that's nice. I can bypass your IP check by **FORGING** any proxy IP I'd like... Never **EVER** trust the IP-detection headers, except for `REMOTE_ADDR`. That one comes directly from the TCP stack and is where the connection came from. The rest are SUGGESTIONS and trivial to forge.

Comment: I'd be highly interested in the $userIp contents. The only positive value I could think of is a domain name in one of the headers. However, most likely it's rather trivial typo-like mistake in effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($ipCheck != 0) //banned
else //not banned
```

You are counting the number of rows returned from your query. If one or more
rows was returned the IP address was banned.

Comment: Will accept this in 9 minutes when it lets me. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = mysql_query ("SELECT ip FROM blocklistIp WHERE ip = '" . mysql_escape_string(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR')) . "' LIMIT 0,1");
if ( mysql_num_rows ($sql) ) {
 // code here match found
}
else {
 // no match found
}
```